# Runtime parameters for a systemd service

Tags: environment-variables, startup, systemd, services, boot-process

I am a little confused about how runtime parameters are normally supplied to a systemd service. The general idea I have is that the following happens:

There is a file that contains the environment variable settings, e.g., /etc/sysconfig/mydaemon

Then there is the unit file, e.g., mydaemon.service (not sure where this is located)

Inside of the unit file is a line such as the following:

```
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/mydaemon
```

When the service is started, the settings file is opened then each setting is supplied to main as argc/argv. Is that right?

Comment: See this [blog post](http://patrakov.blogspot.com/2011/01/writing-systemd-service-files.html) for a start.  A service file doesn't accept arguments to my knowledge.  You must pass the service file  variable options contained in the file referenced by the `EnvironmentFile`

Comment: I did actually read that blog before I posted. It does not make everything clear. For example, it does no explain how the service code accesses the options settings, among other things.

Comment: Also, just as an aside, why is there a dash in the EnvironmentFile setting shown above?

Comment: Look at the section under Configuration.  That file snippet is a plain `.conf` file stored in `/etc`  You can write to and store variables in that file then pass the filename in the `EnvironmentFile` line.  To actually pass the values use the `ExecFile` line and pass the options through string expansion.

Comment: Re: Dash.  From the systemd.exec man page: The argument passed should be an absolute filename or wildcard expression, optionally prefixed with "-", which indicates that if the file does not exist, it will not be read and no error or warning message is logged.

Answer (score 4):

The `EnvironmentFile` option should be set to the full path of the file containing any necessary environment variables needed for proper operation of the executable.
See `EnvironmentFile` in [`man systemd.exec`](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html) for details.

Arguments to the executable can be included in the "ExecStart" parameter. This mechanic is separate and distinct from the "EnvironmentFile" option. You can find more documentation at http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html